# splitting the right hand column into 2 rows, bootstrap, html, css

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am trying to find a way to split a column in two.

The eventual goal is to display three completely different things in each area.

For example a PDF in area 1, a pdf in area 2 and a video in area 3.

Responsiveness isnt really needed, as it'll only ever be viewed on 1 size screen!

I have attached a picture:

[image: What im looking for.]

```
<body>
<section class="intro">
<row>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 left">
<p>
Area 1
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right">
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <p>
    Area 2
    </p>
    </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <p>
  Area 3
    </p>
    </div>


  </div>

</row>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row text-center no-gutters">
      <div class="col bg-danger">
        Area 1
      </div>
      <div class="col">
          <div class="col bg-success">
            Area 2
          </div>
          <div class="col bg-primary ">
            Area 3
          </div>
      
      </div>
     </div>
        
</body>

</html>
```

may be this could help :)

Comment: Exactly what im after! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .area1
  {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  }
  .area2
  {
  background-color:green;
  height:50px;
  }
   .area3
  {
  background-color:blue;
  height:50px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <p class="area1">area1 add this</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <div class="row  area2">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p class="area2">area2 add this</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row  area3">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p class="area3">area3 add this</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are not recommended. Try to highlight which part of the code answers the question or explain what was going wrong requiring this code. You can do that by editing your answer and adding the necessary context.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
      .block {
        min-height: 100px;
        text-align:center;
        /* border:1px solid #666; */
      }

      .block.first {
        background: lightgreen;
      }

      .block.second {
        background: lightcoral;
      }

      .block.third {
        background: lightblue;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col block first">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 block second">
              One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 block third">
              One of three columns
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```